# Quantifying and communicating a variables contribution to the variation in another, where the sum or product of the variables is known exactly

Tags: variance, covariance, logarithm

Two vectors, $a$ and $b$ either sum or multiply to exactly equal $c$. How can I quantify and communicate the contribution of variance in $a$ or $b$ to the the variance in $c$? $a$ and $b$ could either be independent or dependent.

Comment: If "a" were constant, var(c) = var(b). So the marginal variance is var(a)+var(b)+2cov(a,b) but the conditional variance is var(b).

Comment: Re "the interpretation is difficult:" Since in either case the variance of $c$ easily can be less than either those of $a$ or $b$, you would conclude that each of $a$ and $b$ "explain" more than 100% of the variance of $c$.  What could this possibly mean?  What would be the point?  Do these questions have any kind of statistical or mathematical meaning or use?

Comment: What's difficult to understand about the negative covariance case? If a=b and c=a-b then c is 0 all the time, but if you condition on a then c's takes different values within the same stratum of a. conditional variance is not always lower than marginal variance.

Comment: It's difficult to see how the mathematical question you are asking has any relevance to that statistical problem.

Comment: You can help us out by telling us the answer in a very simple case.  Take two-dimensional vectors $a=(2,-2)$ and $b=(-3,3).$ They sum to $c=(-1,1).$  Please tell us what you mean by "variances" of these three vectors and what the "contributions" of $a$ and $b$ are.  Your answer to the question where $b=(-2,2)$ (and therefore $c=(0,0)$) would also be of interest, because the answer that has been posted falls apart in that case.

Comment: So far, you haven't asked us anything about a model except to state it's not a regression model.  That's why this post is unanswerable!

Comment: @whuber Variance would ideally be the standard deviation squared i.e. Var(a)=4Var(a)=4, but it could also be another measure of the dispersal in the data. The contribution to variance is: how much does the variance in aa or bb contribute to the variance in cc. Simply taking Var(a)/Var(c)=Var(a)/(Var(a)+Var(b)+2Cov(a,b))Var(a)/Var(c)=Var(a)/(Var(a)+Var(b)+2Cov(a,b)) also fails in your example. In any case where 2Cov(a,b))2Cov(a,b)) is negative, this approach also doesn't make sense.

Comment: @whuber - I wouldn't assume that because you cant answer a question, its "unanswerable". It would be helpful if you could be more clear why this is such an "unanswerable" question in your opinion.

Comment: @Sarracenia, See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poster stated in a comment that it was not necessary that variance be used so unless the mean of $a$ and $b$ are both zero I think it makes more sense to consider the squared Euclidean length rather than the variance so if $P_a = aa'/(a'a)$ is the projection onto the space spanned by $a$ we have:

$c = P_a c + (I - P_a) c$

and

$||c||^2 = ||P_a c||^2 + ||(I-P_a) c||^2$

so we can consider the ratio:

$||P_a c||^2 / ||c||^2$

as the proportion of the squared length of $c$ in the direction of $a$.

If the mean of $a$ and of $b$ were both $0$ then variance would be appropriate and, in fact, the above is equivalent to $var(P_a c) / var(c)$ in that case.

Comment: @g-grothendieck Thank you for this answer. It is a really interesting solution. I am comparing it to other options including Sobol Indices, correlation coefficients, and marginal variance - once I have a solution I will mark it as answered. Not sure who gave this a -1, but it seems good to me. Also, its a shame this post has been put on hold for so long as it would be really good to get some more replies.